# OpenCl maximum work-items per compute unit

Tags: c++, opencl

I am writing an `OpenCL` code to find an optimum work-group size to have maximum occupancy on GPU. For this, I want a function that returns the maximum number of work-items per compute unit.

Basically, I am deriving this from a `CUDA` code and I want an equivalent of `maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor`.
In CUDA these were the values returned on device query:
Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
Maximum number of threads per block:           1024

In OpenCL:
CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE:    1024

In CUDA it doesn't asks for kernel info to return this value.
I need an equivalent function for OpenCL.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

To get the maximum number of work-items per compute unit, use [clGetDeviceInfo()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/2.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html) together with the CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE flag. This will return the "maximum number of work-items in a work-group that a device is capable of executing on a single compute unit", which is pretty much what you want.

The optimum work-group size depends not only on the device, but also on the specific kernel being used. For this purpose you can use the [clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/2.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo.html) function with the CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE flag. This "returns the preferred multiple of workgroup size for launch", which is a "performance hint".

If you're using the C++ bindings, use the getInfo() and getWorkGroupInfo() methods with device and kernel objects, respectively.